# Cannot achieve consistent overflow scrolling with nested CSS grids

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Are the observed differences between firefox (left) and chrome (right) due to

- me doing something wrong/incomplete?
- browsers differences/issues?

Note: If the inner grid is commented out, both browsers are consistent.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 0px;
 background: transparent;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style='border: 10px solid steelblue;' scroll='auto'>
  <div style='display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr; grid-template-rows: auto; border: 10px solid orange;'>
    <!-- remove the following line to get consitent behavior -->
    <div style='display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr; grid-template-rows: auto; border: 10px solid red;'>
      <div style="overflow: auto;">
        <div style='width: 2000px; border: 10px solid green;'>Content</div>
      </div>
    <!-- remove the following line to get consitent behavior -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `min-width: 0` to the first div child. https://jsfiddle.net/zams9nfe/1/

Comment: Yes, thank you again, Michael!